# react onMountUpdate append something to ref dom appended twice on hot reload

Tags: reactjs

I have this React component, where I have to append something to the dom, but when hot reloading this element is appended twice, probably somehow the old one isn't removed. How do I make sure it is removed?

class ShessComponent extends Component {

myRef!: React.RefObject

ss?: Shess

constructor(props: any) {
super(props)
this.myRef = React.createRef()
}

componentDidMount() {
if (this.myRef.current) {
console.log(this.myRef.current.children, this.ss)
if (this.ss) {
return;
}
this.ss = Shess.init()
this.myRef.current.appendChild(this.ss.el)
}
}

render() {
return (

)
}
}